# Encoding Italian from .json file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to send an email with python, however I am having issues getting specific languages to work.
I am putting my text in a json key it looks like this:

```
"languages" : {
   "italiano": "text" 
}
```

the text is this:

> La mia Richiesta concerne anche altri servizi e altre società per le
>   quali ricoprite la carica di titolare del trattamento dei dati
>   personali in ottemperanza alle disposizioni del comma 7 dell’art. 4
>   del regolamento GDPR. In ottemperanza alle disposizioni del comma 3
>   dell’art. 12 del regolamento GDPR siete obbligati a confermare
>   l’avvenuta cancellazione senza ingiustificato ritardo e, comunque, al
>   più tardi entro un mese dal ricevimento di questa Richiesta.

However, when I try to parse the text I get a decode error, the text is not ascii. I tried setting my `open()` function to `encode('utf-8')` but that didn't seem to do the trick neither. I am actually having this issue with a lot of different languages (german, czech, etc).

This is my code for parsing the text

```
with open("config.json", 'r', encoding='utf8') as c:
    config = json.load(c)
```

The json above is inside of `the config.json` file.

one of the errors is `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 60: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: can you please post the first 200 characters or so of the file?

Comment: This is the entire config.json http://lazybin.wtf/p/9G7E38ai#UWeY565sJLWpCQFWtUTEpMzYaDGfoj31KhpIXjywABs=

Comment: Unicode **Encode** Error is not a decode error! You have correctly decoded the file and got a non ascii character  U+2019 which is a RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (`’`). The error is raised later in your code...

Comment: Is there a way to just send it regardless or do I have to swap all of them out?

Comment: You need to post the code that raises this error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 60: ordinal not in range(128)`. You're trying to encode a unicode character that doesn't exist in the `ascii` character set. You need to change the encoding to `utf-8`.

Comment: My `with open()` has encoding='utf8' set

Comment: Yes, but that's not where the `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character` error is coming from, at least not in the code snippet you posted. Note it says _encode_, not _decode_. Encoding happens when you go from a `str` to `bytes` (writing to file or buffer).

Comment: ah I see, when I encode the text to utf-8 I get a lot of weird characters that shouldn't be there or an error that the byte can't be found, any way for python to just send it?